# Add button into corner of load ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide, android-relativelayout

I have a ImageView that its loaded by a glide. After loaded (using parameter fitcenter to keep the proportion) I want to add the button into the right top corner. My problem is that I dont know what is the final size of the picture in a runtime.

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter? Button should always be same size. Just wrap your `ImageView` with `FrameLayout` and add into it `Button` with gravity `right|top`.

Button will stay at right-top when image loads to whatever size.

Comment: yes its matter bacause its a expand photo button and I need to place it like this (edit main question)

Comment: I don't understand. What I proposed will accomplish exactly what you described.

Comment: It wont- the padding is diffrent because it depend of imageSize- the button should be always in the corner of visible image